# convert byte array to Bitmap Android

Tags: android, arrays, inputstream, image, bitmapfactory

I changed the Android BluetoothChat sample project to transfer files over Bluetooth. I succesfully transfered text files and print them on a ListActivity. I want to do the same thing with an image, but couldn't make it work. There is a Handler object that sends the byte array received at the InputStream to the UserInterface. There I need to convert this bytearray to an image. I tried the following but doesn't work:

```
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            myImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuf, 0, readBuf.length));
            //the following lines would actually display the text of the file in the ListActivity
            //String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            //mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

The handler code that sends messages to the UI looks like following:

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1,buffer).sendToTarget();
```

**ANSWER**
I read many other posts and I found somebody else that successfully made it work. he used a little trick that saved me. I won't give the answer here because it's explained in a better way in the questions page [Sending image from android to PC via bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797372/sending-image-from-android-to-pc-via-bluetooth)

Thanks everybody for your help though

Comment: myImg has a reference to an image I am using on the UI. After I hit send, the Image dissapears. I guess there is no correct Bitmap to replace with.

Comment: any error or exception ? are you sure it is an image ? did you try to save it somewhere and open it with a regular image viewer ?

Comment: This is what I get in the log files. Like 20 times after I hit "send Image" in the other device. tag skia --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset, int length)` method to get bitmap from byte array.

Comment: I read many posts about the problem I am facing and it could be that I am not reading the whole inputstream in a bytearray before sending it to the UI. Hopefully I will be back with a solution.