# File is not transferred completely (Android)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I am developing an Android App to send a file via bluetooth to a java server using the [BlueCove library version 2.1.0](http://bluecove.org/) based on [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797372/sending-image-from-android-to-pc-via-bluetooth). At the beginning everything looks fine, but the file will not transfered completly. Only about 7KB of 35KB.

**Android**

```
private void sendFileViaBluetooth(byte[] data){
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    btSocket.connect();
    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write( data );
        outStream.write("end of file".getBytes());
        outStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally{
            try {
            outStream.close();
            btSocket.close();
            device = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    }
}
```

**PC Server**

```
InputStream inStream = connection.openInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

File f = new File("d:\\temp.jpg");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (f);

InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);

int bytes = 0;
boolean eof = false;

while (!eof) {
    bytes = bis.read(buffer);
    if (bytes > 0){
        int offset = bytes - 11;
        byte[] eofByte = new byte[11];
        eofByte = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, offset, bytes);
        String message = new String(eofByte, 0, 11);

        if(message.equals("end of file")) {
            eof = true;
        } else {
            fos.write (buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
    }
}

fos.close();
connection.close();
```

I tried already to split the byte array before writing:

```
public static byte[][] divideArray(byte[] source, int chunksize) {
    byte[][] ret = new byte[(int)Math.ceil(source.length / (double)chunksize)][chunksize];

    int start = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(source,start, start + chunksize);
        start += chunksize ;
    }

    return ret;
}

private void sendFileViaBluetooth(byte[] data){

    [...]

    byte[][] chunks = divideArray(data, 1024);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)Math.ceil(data.length / 1024.0); i += 1) {
        outStream.write( chunks[i][1024] );
    }

    outStream.write("end of file".getBytes());
    outStream.flush();

    [...]

}
```

Every help or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any of this. The canonical way to copy a stream in Java is this:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
out.close();
```

Same at both ends. TCP/IP will do all the chunking for you. All you need to do is cope correctly with varying size reads, which this code does.

Comment: But then the file will also not transfer completely. Is there really TCP used by transmit data over Bluetooth SPP?